# Flex - Show text at specific video points

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flex4

I'm using the VideoPlayer component in flex 4 to display a clip. I have about 3 or 4 notes that I want to appear at specific points of the video, sort of like caption but not quite. I'm trying to figure out how to use VideoPlayer time to cause another element to appear (text area with the note in it), but can't seem to get it. I'm a bit of a beginner so an answer for the stupid is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using spark.components.VideoPlayer.  Add an event listener to respond to the playheadUpdate event (spark.events.VideoEvent.PLAYHEAD_UPDATE) and check the value of playheadTime (playhead position, measured in seconds, since the video starting playing) to determine whether it is time to display your text.